# How to sort excel columns from outlook via VBA. Code excutes by doesn't sort

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, outlook

I'm parsing through a few thousand emails scanning for errors. The parsing code dumps the result into excel unsorted into 4 columns. A: Hits, B: Total, C: Percentage, D: User.

This works fine. However I want to sort this data by total hits (or percentage) without having to do it manually in excel. This is because this is generating up a report with multiple other field groups that I want to sort each set.

The problem is nothing I've come up with is able to actual sort from outlook. The code executes without errors but nothing happens. I was able to use the following to sort in an excel macro successfully.

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
        Call .Range("A3:D30").Sort(Key1:=Range("A3"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo)
    End With
End Sub
```

I then placed just the call line into my outlook vba code, defined everything (Excel Object Library is referenced)

```
        With xlSheet

            If i > 0 Then hitp = Round(hits / i * 100, 1) Else hitp = "0"

            Dim vstr As Variant
            Dim temph As String

            j = 2
            .Range("A1:D1").Merge
            .Range("A1:D1").Value = "Basic Errors"
            .cells(j, 1).Value = "Total Hits:"
            .cells(j, 2).Value = "Total Sent:"
            .cells(j, 3).Value = "Percentage:"
            .cells(j, 4).Value = "Agent:"

            For Each vstr In userhit.Keys()
                j = j + 1
                temph = userhit(vstr)
                If temph = "" Then temph = "0"
                .cells(j, 1).Value = temph
                .cells(j, 2).Value = userhit(vstr) + userclean(vstr)
                .cells(j, 3).Value = Round(userhit(vstr) / (userhit(vstr) + userclean(vstr)) * 100, 1) & "%"
                .cells(j, 4).Value = vstr
                DoEvents
            Next

            Call .Range("A3:D30").Sort(Key1:=Range("A3"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo)

        End With
```

I'm using dictionaries (14 of them) to track various things which is why sorting them in vba before dumping would be far more tedious though possibly doable if I get desperate. Sadly this doesn't sort anything in Excel despite running without errors and working if I copy it into an excel macro.

I've also seen another way of doing the sort like shown in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220127/sorting-excel-range-in-class-module-from-outlook-or-access-vba

```
With xlSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range((LeftColStr & RowStart & ":" & RightColStr & RowEnd))
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
End With
```

But in the end that didn't work for him or me when I tried. So I switched to this current method thinking it would be easier but it's not. The code does work if it's in an excel macro, but despite executing in outlook it doesn't work. Any help would be massively appropriated.

Comment: Did you try with the correct code: `Key1:=.Range("A3")` (dot before Range)? You'll have to do this modification anyway even if it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @A.S.H I think you found the issue. This works in Excel without the '.' since it defaults to the activesheet. I'll have to wait till I get back to work tomorrow to test it out. I'll update here if it works.

Comment: it works for me if you use `.Range("A3:D30").Sort Key1:=.Range("A3"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo`, i.e.: remove `Call`, remove parenthesis and add that dot before 2nd `Range` occurrence

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @A.S.H for the tip of the missing '.'

It worked in excel without it since they have a default of using the active sheet. It now works!

```
Call .Range("A3:D30").Sort(Key1:=.Range("A3"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo)
```